# MySQL Replace table from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 active database connections, I need to replace a number of tables from 'connection1' with that of `connection2`. The structures may, or may not be same, (depending if we make changes to the `connection1` table.

I would assume I should do a complete table dump and replace keys where neccesary, but I really have no idea how to do this :)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the build in system command in PHP and mysqldump to first dump the data (export) to a file, then used system() again with mysql to import it into the new table and replace the old one.

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Schema and Data sync](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) tools in dbForge Studio for MySQL. It will help you to compare two databases on different servers, map tables and fields, generate and run synchronization script.